# Наследование ООП private

Tags: php

Не понимаю, пишут, то, что private свойства и методы не наследуются. Почему не наследуются, если класс Worker унаследовал приватные свойства от User?

```
<?php
    class User
    {
        private $name;
        private $age;

        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->age;
        }

        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function getAge()
        {
            return $this->age;
        }

        public function setAge($age)
        {
            $this->age = $age;
        }

    }
?>


<?php
    class Worker extends User
    {
        private $salary;

        public function getSalary()
        {
            return $this->salary;
        }

        public function setSalary($salary)
        {
            $this->salary = $salary;
        }

    }

    $worker = new Worker();
    $worker->setSalary(1000);
    $worker->setName('Коля'); //метод родителя
    $worker->setAge(25); //метод родителя

    echo $worker->getSalary();
    echo $worker->getName(); //метод родителя
    echo $worker->getAge(); //метод родителя
?>
```

Теперь же не надо создавать свойство $name для Worker, значит оно унаследовалось

Comment: всё наследуется. Просто напрямую обратится нельзя ($obj->privateField)

Comment: Метод getName в классе User поправьте пожалуйста, а то он age возвращает :)

Answer (score 1):

Они не видны, но они наследуются. Обращаетесь же вы к ним через публичные методы

Наследуется всё, а вот доступ методы производного класса могут получить только к public и protected полям/методам. А методы базового класса, унаследованные производным, имеют доступ к приватным полям базового класса внутри объекта производного класса, и физически приватные поля базового класса присутствуют, конечно, в экземплярах производного.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
    private $field = 5;

    public function getField()
    {
        return $this->field;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    private $field = 1;

    public function getField2()
    {
        return $this->field;
    }
}

$obj = new B;
var_dump($obj->getField(), $obj->getField2());
```

Каким будет результат? А если `private` заменить на `public` или `protected`?

В этом и заключается различие. Для этого примера с `private` полем в объекте класса `B` будет **два разных** свойства `field`. Одно `private` класса `A`, одно класса `B`. К каждому доступ могут получать только методы класса, в котором это свойство объявлено.

Зачем такое сделано? Вы вольны в классе называть свойства так как вам удобно, и не беспокоиться о том, что такие же имена могут использоваться где-то в других классах по дереву наследования. У вас есть `private` свойство, оно ни с чем не пересекается по имени, обратиться к нему вы можете только из этого класса.

Если в этом примере вместо `private` сделать `protected` - то поле будет наследоваться и оно будет видно одно и то же в обоих методах.